# Cyanogenic and Fluorine Compounds in Pharmaceutical Science

Tags: pharmacology

I was wonder what it was specifically that make things such as Lexapro safe when it came to its Fluoride and nitrile bonds. Why doesn't Lexapro break down into cyanide? Is it just minimal because the chemical is so large it has more mass? Is it like just priming genetic code so that it will chemically metabolize into a safe compound once pharmacokinetics steps in? I know that flourine in particular binds to calcium and sodium and so I'm assuming that's the pathway it bonds to, which is good because they have a wide range of uses.

Comment: Fluorine attached to a phenyl ring is not equivalent to a free fluoride ion hence it does not help in binding to calcium or sodium. The same goes for the cyano group. Fluoro group is usually added to the molecules in order to increase their "stay" in the body. Such compounds are more soluble in the fat and hence are excreted/metabolized slowly.

Comment: This is helpful, and I have also looked into Seligiline metabolism. Do they break down into a safe compound to be excreted, or do they just avoid breaking off of the chemical and goes out the body without breaking off? I'm assuming for the same reason the chemicals might increase their stay, they also would be harder to break apart.

Comment: Nitriles in latex gloves for example are a situation it seems where some people can have an allergic reaction, but it is a compound containing cyanide in which it does not break off and go into the body. However, there's examples of people's bodies reacting as though it may be possible as autoimmune.

Comment: Pharmaceutical companies, when they release medicines for public use, they have spent billions of dollars in research followed by very very rigorous testing following the regulatory procedure of the land. This testing does include excretion studies and studying the metabolic products. You have to consult a doctor who knows more it. –

Comment: Both are bonded to phenyl rings. There is no mechanism that would cleave either the $\ce{C-F}$ or the $\ce{C-CN}$ bond at any meaningful rate.